# How to pass arguments from html to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

**html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample Burndown Chart</h1>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**myscript.js:**

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Burndown Chart',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Day 1', 'Day 2', 'Day 3', 'Day 4', 'Day 5', 'Day 6',
                   'Day 7', 'Day 8', 'Day 9', 'Day 10']
    },        
    series: [{
      name: 'Ideal Burn',
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.25)',
      lineWidth: 2,
      data: [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
    }, {
      name: 'Actual Burn',
      color: 'rgba(0,120,200,0.75)',
      marker: {
        radius: 6
      },
      data: [100, 110, 85, 60, 60, 30, 32, 23, 9, 2]
    }]
  });
});
```

The code works, and I do see the pretty burndown chart.

However, can someone please show me the easiest/correct way to pass arguments to the javascript function inside myscript.js for the **data**.

In other words, instead of:

Day 1, Day 2, Day 3...

I would pass in actual dates.

Instead of 100, 110, 85...
I would pass in the correct data values.

Please advise.

EDIT:

A hashmap is passed from the server side to the front end.

```
return descriptor.getHtml("view", data);
```

the view is the html file.

so I can access any value/object in the **data**, using $key_name

Comment: It really depends--how are you getting your data?

Comment: Where would you get these values from? A server? User input? Computed?

Comment: The values are computed and passed down by the server. Using Java on the server side. I can access the data by referencing the variable name and prefixing the name with a $.

Comment: Good to know, and thanks for the kudos, can you show me the response from the server?

Comment: Please see edit. (bad edit, fixed now)

Comment: Ok, but how does the object looks like, is it a JSON? Can you copy a fragment of the response using Chrome Dev Tools or Firefox Dev Tools?

Comment: Java/server side writes the object to html. Just know that I can access any variable using $<var_name> in my html file. Is there a way to pass an argument to the container using the <div> tag?

Comment: Test from the browser console if you can access the data object through Javascript with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I think you should get data from a server, if that's possible in your context, as @LMulvey suggested it depends on how you get the data from. Assuming you have and API to get values, you could use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method from jQuery and the within the response fill the values of `data` and `categories` of your chart. Hope that helps, cheers, sigfried.

Comment: Thx @sigfried. Please see comment above.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, simply write:

`<script>var myVar = 'myValue';</script>`

to the page from your back-end logic. 
Your variable will now be available as a global variable. Be sure to include this script on the page before the script that tries to access it is loaded and executed.

Comment: great idea, but I can't include the script before due to design constraints.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working for me:

**html:**

```
<h1>Sample Burndown Chart</h1>
<div id="container" data-param1="heyaaa" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**myscripts.js:**

```
$(function () {

  var $cont = $("#container");
  var val1 = $cont.data('param1');
  alert(val1);

  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: val1,
      x: -20 //center
  },
```

The title of the chart was updated correctly.

Is this the right way of doing things?
or is there a cleaner way?
Ill probably have to add param2 and param3 as well. (looks kind of ugly to my eyes)